# Rails simple form input with collection saves id's of object instead of names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Rails simple form input with collection saves id's of object instead of names.
I have simple collection:

```
 = address_f.input :state, collection: State.all, :required => true, label: t('content.realty.state')
```

State have id and name column. As output in view I see a proper select with proper values, but on save the id's are saved instead of names.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For associated objects normally you want to store the id of the object but if you really want to store the name you can use :value_method.

```
address_f.input :state, collection: State.all, :required => true, label: t('content.realty.state'), value_method: :name
```

See simple_form doc: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collections

Comment: that's do the job.. Thanks Dan